# Why is my mod_rewrite not working?

Tags: customization, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite, htaccess

Ok I have a WP site using the permalink structure of `/%category%/%postname%/`

I have built it in the way of page templates, using category queries inside, i.e.

**page-help.php**

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=help');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
     <!--content-->
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**page-about.php**

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=about');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
     <!--content-->
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Pretty simple. The problem I have is, I need an archive by year for the news section. I did this by just making the **archive.php**  have the same layout as **page-news.php** and just query the posts in the news category. *-this is fine in my case because news is, and will only ever be the content to be archived.

My news category (latest-news) is a child of the about category (about), so when I go to the news section, the url is:

> www.example.com/about/latest-news/

On the news page is use the following code to list the archives;

```
<!-- Gets archive for news-->   
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=news_article');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
     <?php wp_get_archives('type=yearly'); ?> 
<!--Ends archive for news-->
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The links it generates naturally lead me to

> www.example.com/2000
>
> www.example.com/2001

etc. I want the rewrite to change them to

> www.example.com/about/latest-news/2000
>
> www.example.com/about/latest-news/2001

I have modified the .htaccess in the WP route to this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress  
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>     
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]    
RewriteRule  /([0-9]+/?)$  /about/latest-news/$1     [NC,L]  #Added this line
</IfModule>
```

But I am having no luck, the url remains as

> www.example.com/2000

I have the issue of not knowing wether my re-write is wrong, wether I should be putting this line of re-write in a different htaccess elsewhere, or if WordPress is overwriting it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I mis-read your question in my original answer. In your desired destination URL, where are you expecting the phrase "latest-news" to come from?

Comment: @Adam Backstrom I have edited the question to make it more clear. The /about/latest-news section is where the news page is found. I just want the mod_rewrite to add 'about/latest-news/' before a string of 4 numbers in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your additional line comes too late. The rule before catches everything you want to match.
Second, it doesn’t what you want. Your …

```
RewriteRule  /([0-9]+/?)$  /about/latest-news/$1     [NC,L]
```

… matches requests like `example.com//0000000000000000000/` or `example.com/about/latest-news/2010/` (infinite loop!).
The first argument for `RewriteRule` omits the starting `/`.

To match year archives you need rather:

```
RewriteRule  ^(\d\d\d\d)/?$  /about/latest-news/$1     [NC,L]
```

I’m not sure if you really need mod_rewrite for that. Try the following line above the rewrite block:

```
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/(\d\d\d\d)/?$ /about/latest-news/$1
```

You have to tell WordPress about your custom archive [permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permalinks). You should find enough good examples under the tag.

Comment: Thanks the Redirect worked. Now I have a new problem, but that is the answer to this question, so thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Wordpress without mod_rewrite ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)), all urls are like `myblog.com/index.php?p=12`. With mod_rewrite you can create pretty urls, like `myblog.com/mypost`. How this works is that Apache internally rewrites the url `myblog.com/mypost` to `myblog.com/index.php?p=12`, before handing the request over to Wordpress.

So mod_rewrite is used to create pretty urls for your blog, but it will not rewrite the links Wordpress *generates* for you.

To solve your problem, you shouldn't have to change the mod_rewrite rules.